# No beep when using SCO for speech recognition (ANDROID)

Tags: android, bluetooth, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I've put together a quick demo of a problem I'm having. When I run the following code, the text is read but there is no beep to prompt for STT and no double beep for the timeout (error 7) but it is running.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    TextToSpeech oTTS;
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    String sTextToSpeak;
    String sTextFromSpeech;
    SpeechRecognizer sr;
    Intent iSRIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final AudioManager tmpAm = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        BroadcastReceiver scoBR = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

                Log.i(TAG, "onReceive");

                // SCO Connected
                if (intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1) ==
                        AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "SCO Connected");

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Log.i(TAG, "Speaking:" + sTextToSpeak);

                    // TODO fix deprecation
                    //noinspection deprecation
                    oTTS.speak(sTextToSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);
                }

                // SCO Disconnected
                if (intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1) ==
                        AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "SCO Disconnected");
                }
            }
        };

        // Start scoBroadcastReceiver
        try {
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED);
            registerReceiver(scoBR, intentFilter);
            Log.i(TAG, "SCOBroadcastReceiver registered");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "SCOBroadcastReceiver already registered");
        }

        oTTS = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {

                Log.i(TAG, "onInit called");

                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

                    params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "utteranceId");

                    params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM,
                            String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL));

                    Log.i(TAG, "TTS initialized");

                    Log.i(TAG, "Start SCO");

                    tmpAm.startBluetoothSco();

                } else {

                    Log.i(TAG, "Couldn't initialize TTS");
                }
            }
        });

        oTTS.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStart(String s) {

                Log.i(TAG, "UtteranceProgressListener onStart called");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDone(String s) {

                Log.i(TAG, "UtteranceProgressListener onDone called");

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Log.i(TAG, "Calling sr");

                        sr.startListening(iSRIntent);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String s) {

                Log.i(TAG, "UPL onError:" + s);
            }
        });

        sTextToSpeak = "This is a test";

        sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getApplicationContext());
        sr.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
            }

            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
                Log.i(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsDb) {
                //Log.i(TAG, "rmsDB:"+rmsDb);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
            }

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech() {
                Log.i(TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int error) {

                Log.i(TAG, "onError:" + error);
                tmpAm.stopBluetoothSco();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle results) {

                ArrayList data = results.getStringArrayList(
                        SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                if (data != null) {
                    sTextFromSpeech = data.get(0).toString();
                } else {
                    sTextFromSpeech = "";
                }

                Log.i(TAG, "onResults:" + sTextFromSpeech);
                tmpAm.stopBluetoothSco();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

                Log.i(TAG, "onPartialResults:" + sTextFromSpeech);
                tmpAm.stopBluetoothSco();
            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

                Log.i(TAG, "onEvent:" + eventType);
            }
        });

        iSRIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_VOICE_SEARCH_HANDS_FREE);
        iSRIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        iSRIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        iSRIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak something...");
        iSRIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
        iSRIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.DICTATION_MODE", false);
        iSRIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.MODE", 1);
        iSRIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.PREFER_OFFLINE", false);
        iSRIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.SUGGESTIONS_ENABLED", false);
        iSRIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.PROFANITY_FILTER", true);
        iSRIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.AUDIO_ENCODING_REQUESTED", false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy called");

        if (oTTS != null) {
            oTTS.stop();
            oTTS.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```